# Python pandas, score the evenness spread of data across time

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm trying to feature engineer a data frame with a time delta in seconds column. I would like to create a new feature that will score higher for data that spreads more evenly across time.

[image]

I've created this sample DF with 2 time lines, one is evenly distributed while the other one is not:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],'timestamp':[
            '2020-09-01 18:14:00',
            '2020-09-01 18:14:01',
            '2020-09-01 18:14:02',
            '2020-09-01 18:14:03',
            '2020-09-01 18:14:04',
            '2020-09-01 19:14:05',
            '2020-09-01 19:14:16',
            '2020-09-01 19:14:18',
            '2020-09-01 19:14:30',
            '2020-09-01 19:14:59'                                                
]})

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
df['delta'] = (df['timestamp']-df['timestamp'].shift()).fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0)).astype('int64') / 1000000000
```

I've googled around and I'm kinda lost, is standard deviation the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

I am just thinking out loud:

```
for x in df['id'].unique():
    print(x, df[df['id']==x]['timestamp'].diff().mean().total_seconds())
```

Produces:

```
1 1.0
2 13.5
```

`.median()` produces:

```
1 1.0
2 11.5
```

`.std()` produces:

```
1 0.0
2 11.269427669
```

Then I would write a function that takes in all of the `means` / `medians` or `std` of the `diff` and return a value determining if it is for example densely packed or not depending on your idea.

And so `13.5` / `11.5` or `id` `2` has a higher average / mean / std meaning that the points are distributed more vastly across time. It is, however, important to check if each `id` has more or less the same amount of rows, I think it would not be smart to compare 2 rows vs 100 rows.

Interesting question and I am looking forward to hear what others will think!

Comment: Thanks for that idea, I'll have a look